# How To Make Laravel Admin Approval

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

im new to laravel. i want to make an admin panel with multiple role, and any role except admin that trying to CRUD, must need Admin approval to implement it. is there any library, or tutorial how to do it, please  i need it to learn.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Spatie Permissions package:

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction

The features you could look at to learn this are Laravel's Gates and Policies, which can be used to restrict access based on criteria.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization